# Hive : with multi insert query: FAILED: SemanticException Should not happened

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using multi insert query for optimization purpose, surely it helps me a lot but with each day run, I can find 3 to 4 id's (having count more than 10 Million) taking too much time at reducer. to fix this I have implemented skewjoin optimization properties but it's throwing

```
"FAILED: SemanticException Should not happened"
```

Properties which I am using

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true;
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;  
set mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type=BLOCK;
SET hive.optimize.skewjoin=true;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
set hive.intermediate.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
set hive.intermediate.compression.type=BLOCK;
set hive.optimize.skewjoin=true;
set hive.skewjoin.key=100000;
set hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks=10000;
set hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split=33554432;
```

Kindly suggest how can I optimize this skew data.(with each new run id's would be different)

Answer (score 0):

```
set hive.optimize.skewjoin=true; ---> set hive.optimize.skewjoin=false;
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.